# Why is my wood looking like army camo?

Tags: materials, color

I'm very new to blender, and I want to create a Tabletop. I followed the tutorial on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghyktnK0sAs, but my output was like so:[image: blender output]

Why is this happening and how may I make it look like wood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this happening and how may I make it look like wood?

There aren't many reasons for this other than you didn't follow the tutorial correctly, because the wood in the tutorial looks completely different.

Tutorials are meant to be watched and re-watched until you get how the stuff works, so this is normal. It is completely normal not to understand everything straight away, I believe this happens to everyone who tries to learn CG and it's OK. You just need to redo it. ...and then possibly re-do it once more, and once more after that, and maybe even after that and so on. This is how learning 3d goes - there is lots of re-doing at first. Watch the tutorial again as many times as you need to and follow it more thoroughly until you understand everything that is done in it and get good results. If you want a more in-depth answer about it than this, you need to share your file so people can see what exactly you did.

Comment: Thanks - turns out I missed a step in the tutorial ;)

Comment: I'm a big fan of your answers, Martynas :). They're just so true...